# Should Views be reused in Preferences?

Tags: android, android-view, android-preferences

I have an Android app in which I use [`Preference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html)s. I am currently developing a custom `Preference` that uses a [`TimePicker`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) for its `View`.

The method that is supposed to give Android the `View` to show is `getView(View, ViewGroup)`. Its first parameter, `View convertView` contains a `View` to reuse if possible.

However, I was thinking of creating the `TimePicker` in the constructor and storing it in a field:

```
public class MyPreference {
    private TimePicker mTimePicker;

    public MyPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mTimePicker = new TimePicker(context);
    }

    public View getView(View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return mTimePicker;
    }
}
```

Are there any problems with this approach, or what would be better?

Comment: Why did you delete this thread without replying? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724982/parsing-wmic-output/23725039

Comment: I found another way, which rendered the question irrelevant. Well, undeleted.