# Parsing WMIC output

Tags: windows, parsing, batch-file, output

I have a BAT script that is supposed to read the current screen resolution to variables. I get the screen resolution with the `wmic desktopmonitor get screenwidth /value` command (for the width, the height is the same thing).

Example output:

```
C:\Users\Pietu1998>wmic desktopmonitor get screenwidth /value


ScreenWidth=1920


ScreenWidth=




C:\Users\Pietu1998>
```

I have two monitors, so it only shows the resolution for the one in use.

I have tried using a `for` loop to skip the first two empty lines and then read the data.

```
set screenwidth=

for /F "skip=2 tokens=*" %%F in ('wmic desktopmonitor get screenwidth /value') do (
    if "%screenwidth%" equ "" (
        echo line: %%F
        set screenwidth=%%F
        echo var: %screenwidth%
        set screenwidth=%screenwidth:~12%
    )
)
```

I am getting the output correctly, because the lines are printed by the first `echo`, but for some reason the second `echo` outputs nothing. The line is not put in the variable.

What am I missing here? I've been googling about it for 2 hours now.

**UPDATE:** I found a way using `findstr` and a temporary file.

```
wmic desktopmonitor get screenwidth /value | findstr "ScreenWidth=." > %temp%\tmp
set /P screenwidth=< %temp%\tmp
del %temp%\tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo var: %screenwidth%` <--- You can't set and use a variable within a loop without some special techniques, like delayed expansion.

Does this do what you need?

```
@echo off
set "screenwidth="
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%F in ('wmic desktopmonitor get screenwidth /value') do (
    if not defined screenwidth set screenwidth=%%F
)
pause
```

Comment: No, `screenwidth` is being set to `%%F` (literally).

Comment: It doesn't do that here.  Did you paste it as shown?